# ADF create REST Dataset BUG

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is there some issue or known bug for creating a REST dataset? From last week I cant create, the screen just freeze, and it does nothing.

[image]

I have already created in the past few REST datasets and they work fine, so this issue is something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI: the issue was confirmed by ADF team and the bug is resolved.

Answer (score 5):

I just tried and it works fine. As a workaround you can try creating a json file and upload it via powershell, here is the json for the dataset I've just created:

```
{
"name": "RestDataset",
"properties": {
    "linkedServiceName": {
        "referenceName": "RestService1",
        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    },
    "annotations": [],
    "type": "RestResource",
    "typeProperties": {
        "relativeUrl": "RelatUrl"
    },
    "schema": []
}
}
```

Modify it to your needs, save it into a .json file and upload it with Set-AzDataFactoryV2Dataset. You can also use Set-AzureRMDataFactoryV2Dataset if you are still using AzureRM.

Hope this helped!

Comment: do you see this in the GUI? Thanks, I also wanted to try with pure JSON code into source control, but my screen keeps freezing :(

Comment: Yes, I've no idea what could it be. Maybe try another browser, or even another pc?

Comment: tried with another pc :) Will try with EDGE as the azure portal app opens that as default (ofc) :D

Comment: Damn, only option I see is upload the json with powershell.

Comment: Is the linked service working fine when you click test connection?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199186/discussion-between-draganb-and-martin-esteban-zurita).